# L2TP/IPSec On Mac Failed to connect

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I am connecting to a VPN Server set up following instructions in  https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn

And I setup the clients following https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#os-x

Under the same LAN, one of my client(OSX 10.14.5, firewall off) connected successfully

```
# Contents of `cat /var/log/ppp.log`
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : l2tp_get_router_address
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.3.1 from dict 1
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : L2TP connecting to server ‘xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx’ (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : IPSec connection started
Tue Jun 11 14:46:46 2019 : IPSec phase 1 client started
Tue Jun 11 14:46:47 2019 : IPSec phase 1 server replied
Tue Jun 11 14:46:47 2019 : IPSec phase 2 started
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : IPSec phase 2 established
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : IPSec connection established
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP received SCCRP
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP sent SCCCN
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP sent ICRQ
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP received ICRP
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP sent ICCN
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP connection established.
Tue Jun 11 14:46:48 2019 : L2TP set port-mapping for en0, interface: 8, protocol: 0, privatePort: 0
```

But the other client(also OSX 10.14.5, firewall off) failed to connect

```
# Contents of `cat /var/log/ppp.log`
Tue Jun 11 14:44:04 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Jun 11 14:44:04 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Jun 11 14:44:04 2019 : l2tp_get_router_address
Tue Jun 11 14:44:04 2019 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.3.1 from dict 1
Tue Jun 11 14:44:04 2019 : L2TP connecting to server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Tue Jun 11 14:44:04 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Tue Jun 11 14:44:24 2019 : L2TP cannot connect to the server
```

Can somebody gives me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `/etc/ppp`.
If there is any file, like `options`, check it out.
There might be:

```
/etc/ppp % cat options
plugin L2TP.ppp
l2tpnoipsec
```

So you should remove the `options` file and then you will get a positive result.